# Intent with extra data not working correctly

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, int

I have two classes. One contains 12 buttons - one for every month of the year. The other contains a dynamic `ImageView`, swipe gestures, and an `arraylist` of images..

I'm trying to call the class with the image arraylist using the buttons in the other class. Also I want to be able to set the arraylist to a certain point in the arraylist when the button is clicked. So for example if I clicked the the February button the array list will be set to display its 32 position which would be 1st February and then and I can swipe through the list normally after that.

I only have an Intent for January so far but it's not working. It looks fine but when i run the app it displays today's image and not the image for the 1st of January.

Button select class

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * declare all buttons from month_select create onClickListener set each button open Quote display
 * activity on the day of there selected month
 */
public class MonthSelect extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    // declaring variables
    // I declare all this but won't use em elsewhere
    private RelativeLayout      r2;
    private Button              january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december;
    private int                 jan, feb, mar, apr, mayy, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec;
    private ImageView           imageView;

    // list of images
    public final static int[]   IMAGE_LIST  = { /* A whole bunch of R.drawables */};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.month_select );
        // set screen orientation to landscape only this can also be done in the manifest
        setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );

        // finding button views
        findViewById( R.id.januaryButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.februaryButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.marchButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.aprilButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.mayButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.juneButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.julyButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.augustButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.septemberButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.octoberButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.novemberButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        findViewById( R.id.decemberButton ).setOnClickListener( this );
        /**
         * QuoteDisplay quotes = new QuoteDisplay(); quotes.imageView();
         * 
         * quotes.getImageList(1); // This is useless
         */

    }// onCreate

    // global onClickListener for all views
    @Override
    public void onClick( final View view )
    {
        switch ( view.getId() )
        {
            case R.id.januaryButton:
                Intent testing = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), QuoteDisplay.class );
                // int pics = MonthSelect.IMAGE_LIST.length;
                testing.putExtra( "imageList", R.drawable.j_1 );
                startActivity( testing );
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "January", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
            case R.id.februaryButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "February", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.marchButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "March", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.aprilButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "April", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.mayButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "May", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.juneButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "June", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.julyButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "July", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.augustButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "August", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.septemberButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "September", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.octoberButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "October", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.novemberButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "November", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;

            case R.id.decemberButton:
                // testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "December", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
        }// switch

    }// onClick

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.month_select, menu );
        return true;
    }// onCreateOption
}// Monthselect
```

Image Display class

```
/**
 * Set up a dynamic imageView that is set to match_parent
 * get the systems date in day of the year
 * Set up array list of images
 * set the ImageView to display the current dates quote image
 * Implement swipe gestures for left and right
 */
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//suppressWarning for imports used for testing that are currently commented out
@SuppressWarnings( "unused" )
public class QuoteDisplay extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{
    // quote_displays RelativeLayout has been given an id = r1
    RelativeLayout      r1;
    private ImageView   imageView;
    TextView            textView;
    GestureDetector     detector;

    // getting the systems date in number of days
    // parsing string date to an integer
    // reducing the integer count by 1 because arrays begin at zero
    // this is to get the correct image
    Calendar            cal                     = Calendar.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint( "SimpleDateFormat" )
    SimpleDateFormat    sdf                     = new SimpleDateFormat( "DDD" );
    String              strDate                 = sdf.format( cal.getTime() );
    int                 parseStrDate            = Integer.parseInt( strDate );
    int                 imageArrayCorrection    = (parseStrDate - 1);
    private int         currentImage            = imageArrayCorrection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.quote_display );
        // setting app screen to landscape mode only
        setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );
        detector = new GestureDetector( this, this );

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra( "imageList", R.drawable.j_1 );
        // calling methods
        imageView();
    }// onCreate

    // Dynamic ImageView
    protected void imageView()
    {
        r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.r1 );
        imageView = new ImageView( this );
        imageView.setImageResource( imageList[imageArrayCorrection] );
        // Setting the parameters of the relative layout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( (int) LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (int) LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
        params.addRule( RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT );
        imageView.setLayoutParams( params );
        r1.addView( imageView );
    }// imageView

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.quote_display, menu );
        return true;
    }

    // registering TouchEvent with GerstureDetector
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event )
    {
        return detector.onTouchEvent( event );

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown( MotionEvent e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    // Swipe gestures for left and right
    public boolean onFling( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY )
    {
        float sensitivity = 50;
        // swipe left check
        if ( e1.getX() - e2.getX() > sensitivity )
        {
            // increase counter to move to the next image
            currentImage++;
            currentImage = (currentImage + imageList.length) % imageList.length;
            imageView.setImageResource( imageList[currentImage] );
            // testing Fling Gesture
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "<- Fling Gesture Left", 100).show();
            return true;
        }
        // swipe right check
        if ( e2.getX() - e1.getX() > sensitivity )
        {
            // decrease counter to go back to an image
            currentImage--;
            currentImage = (currentImage + MonthSelect.IMAGE_LIST.length) % MonthSelect.IMAGE_LIST.length;
            imageView.setImageResource( MonthSelect.IMAGE_LIST[currentImage] );
            // testing Fling Gesture
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fling Gesture Right ->", 100).show();

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress( MotionEvent e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress( MotionEvent e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp( MotionEvent e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    //
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
    }
}// QuoteDisplay/Main
```

Comment: Maybe shorten the code to the relevant bit that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

The correct image is displaying for the date you've chosen.
You're initializing a `Calendar` instance and extract the date from it. Then in your `imageView()` method, you use that image to display, accordingly to your imageList.
The best thing you can do is to make a `Calendar` instance in the `MonthSelect` class, set the time to whatever date you want it to be, and send that in your intent, something like this:

```
case R.id.januaryButton:
    Intent testing = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), QuoteDisplay.class );
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(/* set to first of january */);
    testing.putExtra( "imageList", R.drawable.j_1 );
    startActivity( testing );
    break;
case ...
    // stuff...
```

Then in the `QuoteDisplay` class you can move the following to your `onCreate()`:

```
private int         currentImage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // getting the systems date in number of days
    // parsing string date to an integer
    // reducing the integer count by 1 because arrays begin at zero
    // this is to get the correct image
    Calendar cal = getIntent().getParcable("thatKey"); // Not sure if it's parcable - I have no IDE to test this right now...
    @SuppressLint( "SimpleDateFormat" )
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "DDD" );
    String strDate = sdf.format( cal.getTime() );
    int parseStrDate = Integer.parseInt( strDate );
    int imageArrayCorrection = (parseStrDate - 1);
    currentImage = imageArrayCorrection;
}
```

Which enables you to leave the rest of that code as-is.

At the moment, you're not using the drawable you send to this activity AT ALL. Well, you create a local `int` in your `onCreate()`, which get's disposed of course.
For answer's sake, even though I'm not quite sure what's going on here, this would be the most quick and simple solution:

In your `imageView()` method, change this line:

```
imageView.setImageResource( imageList[imageArrayCorrection] );
```

to this:

```
// Here you get the drawable that you sent to this activity
int drawableId = getIntent().getIntExtra( "imageList", R.drawable.j_1 );
// Now you can set it as resource! Yay!
imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
```

But I truly think this still won't get you the behaviour you want to have...